# How to insert value in upper scope variable in node.js async

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk

I want input `buckets` to `result1`. but i think i have misunderstand about it..
`result2` return this

```
Request {
  domain: null,
  service: Service {
    config: Config {
      credentials: [Credentials],
      credentialProvider: [CredentialProviderChain],
      region: 'ap-northeast-2',
      logger: null,
      apiVersions: {},
      apiVersion: null,
      endpoint: 's3.ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com',
      httpOptions: [Object],
      maxRetries: undefined,
      maxRedirects: 10,

     ...
```

this is my code:

```
exports.printBuckets = () => {
  let result1 = []
  let result2 = s3.listBuckets((err, data) => {
    buckets = data.Buckets
    console.log(buckets); // Got AWS buckets from AWS!
    result1 = data.Buckets;
  });

  console.log(result1); // [] <- I want insert buckets data to here!
  console.log(result2); // Request object what i wrote up 
};
```

how to fix that the value of variable `result1` equals `buckets`?

Comment: The flow does not break by an async call. You can use `async/await` to wait or work in the body of the promise callback.

Comment: For more information take a look: https://javascript.info/async-await

Answer (score 0):

I had a misconception about async / await.. now I fix it using async/await with promise.

```
exports.printBuckets = async () => {
  let result = await s3.listBuckets().promise().then(result => result);

  console.log(result);
};
```